# Зачем нужен 13 элемент таблицы ASCII?

Tags: ascii

Насколько я знаю,в таблице ASCII 10 и 13 элементы значат LF (`'\n'`) и CR соответственно. В консоли, если нажать 'Enter', то сработает именно linefeed. Тогда зачем нужен 13 (carriage return) элемент? Где он используется? И как ввести его в консоли с клавиатуры.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Да, да, для пишущих машинок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть две школы танцев: одна школа танцев от Микрософт а другая школа танцев от Линукса. В школе танцев от Микрософт окончание строки обозначается парой символов CRLF (именно в таком порядке). В школе танцев от Линукса окончание строки обозначается одним символом LF. Вот так и живем. Судя по вопросу, Вы работаете под Линуксом, поэтому у Вас нет в файлах и в консольном вводе символов CR. Где взять символ CR в Линуксе? Можно взять флешку и перенести *.txt файлы, созданные Windows, в Линукс и открыть эти файлы для просмотра. Можно на Линукс написать свою программу и в этой своей программе открыть файл в бинарном режиме и писать туда строки а в конце строк писать пару символов CRLF. Что получится если файлы с разделителями CRLF просматривать в просмотрщиках от Линукс с я лично не знаю, так как сам работаю под Windows. :-) Думаю, что это зависит от просмотрщика. Вполне возможно, что есть линуксовые просмотрщики, которые понимают что бывают разные окончания строки и учитывают возможность просмотра виндовских файлов на Линуксе.

UPD1:

Да, действительно, чтение консоли винды через cin возвращает только LF. Скорее всего это потому, что поток cin открывается системой в текстовом режиме. Сейчас с ходу у меня не получилось ни считать режим открытия cin, ни считать байты из cin в бинарном режиме. Но если в винде открыть обычный файл (который с системной точки зрения тоже является потоком) по чтению в **бинарном** режиме, то оттуда будут читаться и CR и LF. Вернее оттуда будут читаться те символы, которые туда записаны. Но если писать в винде в файл в **текстовом** режиме строки, то в конце строки система добавляет именно пару CRLF. Если же писать в линуксе в **текстовом** режиме строки, то в конце строки система добавляет только LF. Как-то так.

Чтобы Вам система не пудрила мозги попробуйте поэкспериментировать не с системными потоками cin и cout, а с файлами, открытыми как потоки в бинарном и текстовом режиме. Откройте файл как поток в текстовом режиме и напишите в него десяток строк string ну хотя бы методом <<. А потом посмотрите бинарным редактором, что система поставила в качестве разделителя.

Ну вот, чтобы далеко не ходить этот пример выводит в файл именно пару CRLF. Файл открыт в текстовом режиме. Тестировалось под VS2017.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string str = "example of line";

    ofstream offf("examplt.txt");

    offf << str.c_str();
    offf << endl;
    offf << str.c_str();
    offf << endl;
    offf << str.c_str();
    offf << endl;
    offf << str.c_str();
    offf << endl;
    offf << str.c_str();
    offf << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

UPD2:

Теперь проверим посимвольное чтение из файла, открытого в текстовом режиме. Вот пример:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string str;

    ifstream ifff("examplt.txt");

    for (;;) {

        char ch;

        ch = ifff.get();

        cout << (int)ch << " ";

        if (ifff.eof() == true) break;

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Если этот пример запустить под виндой, то видно, что он читает только символ LF, хотя в файле находится пара символов CRLF. То есть при чтении текстовых файлов система фильтрует ввод и вместо CRLF возвращает пользователю только LF. Если входной поток cin открыт системой в текстовом режиме (а скорее всего так и есть), то из него тоже будет читаться только символ LF при нажатии клавиши Enter.

Однако, если в винде создавать файл через консоль командой

```
copy con rr.txt
```

то создается текстовый файл, в котором разделителями служит также **пара** символов CRLF. То есть при таком вводе файла с консоли система записывает в файл **пару** символов CRLF при каждом нажатии клавиши Enter. Напомню, что завершением процесса создания файла с консоли служит сочетание клавиш **CTRL-Z**.

Comment: *"Судя по вопросу, Вы работаете под Линуксом, поэтому у Вас нет в файлах и в консольном вводе символов CR"* Не факт, раз под виндой в текстовом режиме (в файлах и в стандартном вводе) CRLF превращаются в LF.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я давно не работал под виндой в консоли, но сейчас мне вспоминается, что винда честно шлет в консоль CRLF при нажатии клавиши Enter.

Comment: Нет,сижу из под винды,но при нажатии Enter срабатывает именно LineFeed.Скрин с кодом и консолью,как я это проверил - http://prntscr.com/muzbr3 .Второй символ я сам не вводил,он попал туда из буфера входного потока.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat И встроенные в видну Editor и Notepad++ исопльзуют для разделения строк CRLF. При этом Notepad++ еще понимает, что LF тоже разделитель строк, а во встроенное редакторе весь текст получается в одну строку.

Comment: @escape См UPD1 в ответе.

Comment: @escape См UPD2 в ответе.